# c++ std::regex, smatch retains subexpressions only once for their apperance in a pattern string

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following code:

```
    int main()
    {
        regex reg_expr("(\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\))(?:\\s(\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\)))*");
        //regex reg_expr("(\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\))(?:\\s(\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\)))*\\s(\\([A-Z],[A-Z]\\))");
        smatch sm;
        string input("(A,B) (C,D) (F,W) (G,K) (R,M)");
        //string input("(A,B) (C,D) (F,W)");
        if (regex_match(input, sm, reg_expr)) {
            cout << "true\n";
            cout << sm.size() << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < sm.size(); i++) {
                //if (sm[i].length())
                    cout << "submatch number " << i << ": " << sm[i].str() << '\n';
            }
        } else
            cout << "false";
    return 0;
    }
```

Everything works fine except that "smatch sm" has only one substring for each subexpression specified in the regular expression string.
For example, for the following test string:

```
 (A,B) (C,D) (F,W) (G,K) (R,M)
```

which is correctly matched against the

```
 (\([A-Z],[A-Z]\))(?:\s(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)))*
```

regular expression, the "sm" has only tree substrings: one is for the whole string, and the other two are  "(A,B)" and "(R,M)", the "(C,D)", "(F,W)", "(G,K)" are missing but they are matched.

It looks like the `(?:\s(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\)))*` is understood correctly by regex that 0 or more of the subexpressions should be matched, but there seems to be an error that just one subexpression is stored in the `std::smatch sm`.
Is it a library error (which is less likely) or I am doing something wrong? Your help and advice is wellcome!

Comment: That is not how capturing works. You need to use a simple `R"(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\))"` with a regex iterator to collect *multiple matches*, not captured group values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug, but almost a universal behavior (except for PyPi Python `regex` module, .NET and (if compiled with appropriate options) Boost) when repeated captures only store the last matched item in its buffer.

For more details, read [**Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) article.

In your case, you may use a regular [*`std::sregex_iterator`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator):

```
int main() {
    std::regex reg_expr(R"(\([A-Z],[A-Z]\))");
    string input("(A,B) (C,D) (F,W) (G,K) (R,M)");
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), reg_expr);
        i != std::sregex_iterator();
        ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (*i).str() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/GBtCsv)

Note I am using a raw string literal `R"(...)"` where only 1 backslash is needed to escape regex metacharacters.